# How to mock a function that returns base 64 string

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a vue component that has a function:

```
...
reader.onload = () => {
    let base64String = btoa(reader.result);
  };
...
```

The base64 string is from a file input using a FileReader.
I need to pass the base 64 string to the API but on a test with jest, how can I mock reader.onLoad() to return just a simples base64 string?

Thanks.

Comment: atob('some_string') ?

Comment: the question is how to mock a jest test using onload from FileReader and return a base 64 string

Answer (score 1):

On a high level, you can try to move the base64String extraction to its own function, then mock that function:

```
reader.getBase64String = () => {
  return btoa(reader.result)
}

reader.onload = () => {
  let base64String = reader.getBase64String()
  // rest of implementation
};
```

Then, in your test (this is pseudo-code, might not compile):

```
MyTestReader extends Reader {
  this.getBase64String = () => {
    return "SSBsaWtlIHRvIExPTAo="
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but the problem is with FileReader. I don't know how to mock specific function like onload. because I have to simulate a click on input file on view.

Comment: I'm a little confused still by your question.

Are you saying you'd like to add a test for when a user clicks on an input file? If so, you should test these things separately: 1) Test that a method is called with the right arguments when the file is clicked. 2) Test the actual method with those arguments to ensure that the result is what you expect. Test #1, to be honest, is more of an "integration test" rather than a "unit test". You may need to use a different tool, since mocking is mainly intended for unit tests.

Comment: Generally speaking, the ideal unit test is one that tests whether or not a function returns a certain result given a set of arguments. The main point of mocking is to be able to test your methods without the additional setup/environment differences that a production environment. For examp